# Split a string entered by the user in arguments

Tags: c++

how can I split a string entered by the User in arguments?

assuming that a user type: test1 test2 test3

how can i separate each entered values, in a way that i can access these values separately?

Comment: `std::cin >> string1 >> string2 >> string3;` Where string1, string2 and string3 are variables of type `std::string`.

Comment: you can use a delimiter either white space or any other character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) with [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) to extract characters from user input and stores them into string until the delimitation you inform.
sequentially use a vector to store the extracted characters.

something like this:

```
void split(std::vector<std::string> &args, std::string userInput, char delimiter) 
{

    std::stringstream ss(userInput);
    std::string buf;
    while(getline(ss, buf, delimiter)) {
        args.push_back(buf);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please don't encourage that kind of poor (low researched) questions by leaving an answer. This actively hurts the quality of the site.

Comment: i understand but, i only tried to help, what's wrong with that?

Comment: The site isn't meant as a personal help desk. If you want to do that participate at quora or such. Better point out a possible duplicate and flag the question.